# Firebase library for .net maui when migrating from xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, maui

I am migrating my xamarin forms app to .net maui.
I used Xamarin.Firebase.Firestore and Xamarin.Firebase.Auth nuget package from microsoft to use firebase.
What is the alternate for these in .net maui?

Comment: For now, I think you can use the Xamarin versions of these libraries...

Answer (score 1):

These libraries have been updated to support .NET 7/8 so can be used fine with MAUI! I can't see them bringing out new libraries as there's no need for it currently.